# Pesquisar dados de processos judiciais no site do TJSP

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-service

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação ASP.NET com C# que precisará consultar as movimentações de processos judiciais online. Até agora a única maneira que encontrei para conseguir estas informações foi fazer a consulta direto no site do Tribunal de Justiça, fazer o *parse* do  HTML retornado pela página e extrair as informações que desejo. Para isso estou utilizando o HTML Agility Pack.

Existe alguma outra maneira de conseguir estas informações? Um webservice disponibilizado pelo governo ou algum serviço de terceiros que entregue estas informações? Inicialmente estou focando no Tribunal de Justiça do Estado de São Paulo.

Toda ajuda é bem-vinda.

Comment: Sei que é bem antiga a pergunta mas conseguiu alguma coisa com o TJSP? Fiz algo parecido também coletando as informações diretamente do HTML no site do TJSP, mas é algo realmente bem frágil visto que qualquer alteração na estrutura da página iria arruinar o processo.

Answer (score 6):

Trabalho na empresa que desenvolve o sistema utilizado pelo TJSP.

Hoje, o e-Saj é a única interface web de acesso externo que é disponível o acesso. Se não me falhe a memória, não é disponibilizado o acesso via WS às informações.

Mas diversos outros tribunais já estão utilizando o PJe, que é um software desenvolvido pelo CNJ para os tribunais de 1º grau e ele funciona no projeto de interoperabilidade do CNJ chamado MNI.

O TJSP irá implementar também no decorrer deste ano, como diversos outros, então recomendo conhecer o modelo do MNI [nest link](http://www.cnj.jus.br/tecnologia-da-informacao/comite-nacional-da-tecnologia-da-informacao-e-comunicacao-do-poder-judiciario/modelo-nacional-de-interoperabilidade)

Mas ainda assim, o acesso deverá ser acordado com o tribunal.

Comment: Espero que todos os tribunais adotem o modelo desenvolvido pelo CNJ. Fico no aguardo até que TJSP implemente esta solução Obrigado pelas referências.

Comment: @erickalves05 todos os tribunais que implementaram o PJe já possuem o WebService pelo menos em homologação. O WebService para o [SAJ](http://www3.softplan.com.br/saj/index.jsf) já está em implantação

Comment: Link quebrado :(

Comment: @AllanRamos link corrigido o/

Comment: Alguma novidade em relação ao TJSP?

Answer (score 5):

Trabalhei numa empresa que fazia isso... não me lembro sobre este tribunal especificamente, mas o que se fazia normalmente, era entrar em contato com o tribunal por telefone, com a área técnica, e então perguntar se isso é possível.

A empresa que eu trabalhava fez até mesmo alguns acordos com alguns tribunais, para que estes disponibilizassem acesso via web-services, uma vez que é benéfico para ambos.

Comment: Infelizmente o TJSP não respondeu às ligações da nossa empresa. Mas obrigado. Vamos continuar tentando entrar em contato com eles.

Answer (score 5):

Olá,

Imagino que já tenha feito boa parte do trabalho, contudo, caso ainda esteja com dificuldade, segue o endereço fornecido pelo CNJ com uma lista de Web Services, seguindo o padrão MNI, disponibilizados pelos tribunais de justiça regionais que fornecem acesso de consulta ao PJE de sua região.

Segue link atualizado.

http://www.pje.jus.br/wiki/index.php/P%C3%A1gina_principal

Outros links que podem ajudar:

https://www.cnj.jus.br/tecnologia-da-informacao-e-comunicacao/comite-nacional-de-gestao-de-tecnologia-da-informacao-e-comunicacao-do-poder-judiciario/modelo-nacional-de-interoperabilidade/

Tutorial do MNI (Modelo Nacional de Interoperabilidade):

http://www.pje.jus.br/wiki/index.php/Tutorial_MNI

Versões:

http://www.cnj.jus.br/wiki/index.php/Vers%C3%B5es

Sobre o acesso, é como o colega falou, você precisa entrar em contato com cada tribunal para o mesmo fornecer a WSDL de acesso ao WebService disponibilizado pela instancia do PJE do tribunal que deseja acessar.

Att.

Comment: Link quebrado :(

Comment: Link atualizado: http://www.pje.jus.br/wiki/index.php/Utiliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_do_PJe

Answer (score 5):

Olá! Eu criei um script em PHP que parseia o HTML da tela de resultados e exibe um JSON com todos os dados. Talvez seja útil se vc tiver um servidorzinho com PHP para chamá-lo.

Basta executar ou dar um curl no arquivo. Eu deixei o número do processo hard-coded em uma variável, mas é fácil para receber via post ou outro método.

Para quem quiser, vale a pena conferir:

https://github.com/marcosriso/tjsp_processo_leitor

Answer (score 4):

Olá.
Existem empresas que oferecem este tipo de serviço para os advogados.
O principio básico é que o advogado traça um perfil do que ele deseja acompanhar (numero do processo, nome das partes, clientes, ...) e o sistema monitora os tribunais coletando as decisões que se encaixam no perfil e enviando um boletim com o que foi coletado. 
Em São Paulo a AASP (http://www.aasp.org.br/) oferece isto para os seus associados.

Comment: O software que minha empresa está desenvolvendo segue a mesma premissa. Mas este monitoramento precisa ser algo interno do programa, sem influência do advogado. Eu não conhecia a AASP. Obrigado pelo link.